# Proof of a the following formula: $\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)}=\frac{2}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}$

Tags: summation

How can I prove the following combinatorial identity about the harmonic series?

> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)}=\frac{1}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=0}^n
>  \left(\frac{1}{(k+1)} +
>  \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}\right)=\frac{2}{(n+2)}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}$$

Surely, it has to be done by induction, but how do I actually carry out the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(k+1)} +\frac{1}{(n-k+1)}   &= \frac{n-k+1  + k+1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)} \\&= \frac{n +2}{(k+1)(n-k+1)} \end{align}$$ then

$$\frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)} = \frac{1}{n+2} \Bigg(\frac{1}{(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}\Bigg)$$

Thus

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)(n-k+1)} &=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{n+2} \Bigg(\frac{1}{(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}\Bigg)  \\&=\frac{1}{n+2}\sum_{k=0}^n\Bigg(\frac{1}{(k+1)} + \frac{1}{(n-k+1)}\Bigg)  \end{align}$$

And finally notice that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)} = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(n-k+1)} $$

Answer (score 0):

The first step is simply a partial fraction decomposition, while the second one follows from:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{n-k+1}=H_{n+1} $$
by re-indexing $k\to n-k$.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you add some details?

Comment: @user62029: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(n-k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}f(k)$$ for any function $f$.

Comment: I see. Still, that doesn't help me work out a proof. Also, how do you use partial fraction decomposition with induction? Could you show me how to complete the proof?